# Powershell output after zip using

Tags: powershell

In my script I use zip function :

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory( $sourcedir, $zipfilename)
```

but this generate a verbose output in the cmd :

```
CodeBase            : file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
FullName            : System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, *Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
EntryPoint          :
DefinedTypes        : {System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, Sy*stem.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions, System.IO.Compression.SR}
Evidence            : {<System.Security.Policy.GacInstalled version="1"/>
                      , <StrongName version="1"
                      Key="00000000000000000400000000000000"
                      Name="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
                      Version="4.0.0.0"/>
                      , <System.Security.Policy.Url version="1">
                      <Url>file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll</Url>
                      </System.Security.Policy.Url>
```

How can I switch off those messages ?

Comment: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`

Answer (score 0):

Add a pipe and [Out-Null](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849716.aspx) to the lines which are outputting the unwanted messages.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" ) | Out-Null
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory( $sourcedir, $zipfilename) | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices here.

Change syntax (only applicable to the first line):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
```

Cast result to void:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")
```

Pipe result to `Out-Null`:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem") | Out-Null
```

Store in a variable (can be any, but `$null` feels adapted):

```
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")
```

Oddly enough, I didn't manage to find another thread about suppressing command output ... but I know there are a few `;-)`.